# Dynamic segments transition

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

i have read from the officia doc of emberjs 2.6 that :

> Note: A route with a dynamic segment will only have its model hook
>   called when it is entered via the URL. If the route is entered through
>   a transition (e.g. when using the link-to Handlebars helper), then a
>   model context is already provided and the hook is not executed. Routes
>   without dynamic segments will always execute the model hook

so i tried something to see my self how its work :

**post.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    alert("executed");
    return this.get('store').findRecord('post', params.post_id);
  }
});
```

**index.hbs**

```
{{#link-to "post" 1}}
        post.title
{{/link-to}}
```

**index2.hbs**

```
{{#link-to "post" aPostInstance}}
        post.title
{{/link-to}}
```

So when i open index.hbs and click on the link, the model hook is not called, and that what the doc confirm.

But When i open index2.hbs and click on the link, the model hook is called, even if its is a trinsition, not a link reload.

i can understand the second point because i give the route an id, so its use the id to fetch post from the store, but why is this point not described in the doc?

Answer (score 0):

i find the answer in another doc page(why not in the same place in the doc?)

> Calling transitionTo() from a route or transitionToRoute() from a
>   controller will stop any transition currently in progress and start a
>   new one, functioning as a redirect. transitionTo() behaves exactly
>   like the link-to helper.
>
> If the new route has dynamic segments, you need to pass either a model
>   or an identifier for each segment. Passing a model will skip that
>   segment's model() hook (since the model is already loaded).

Comment: The full API is always described [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_model). The Guides are just to start with ember and don't cover everything.